# Bootstrap 4 collapse nav group

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a documentation site with Table of contents in a right hand column and the content in the left hand column. The TOC has several groups containing code similar to below. Is there any way to collapse and expand the sub-menu nav by clicking on the anchor tag? So that the sub menus are are all collapsed when page loads and then the user can expand and collapse as needed.

Orgbrat

```css
.doc-sub-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.doc-sub-menu .nav-link {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  color: #616670;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 34px;
  background: none;
}

.doc-sub-menu .nav-link:first-child {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.doc-sub-menu .nav-link:hover {
  color: #494d55;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
}

.doc-sub-menu .nav-link:focus {
  background: none;
}

.doc-sub-menu .nav-link.active {
  background: none;
  color: #40babd;
}

.body-blue .doc-sub-menu .nav-link.active {
  color: #58bbee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/UserGuide/Items">Adding and Managing Items</a>
<nav class="doc-sub-menu nav flex-column">
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#html">Medications</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#css">Blood Sugars</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#sass">Pharmacies</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#less">Physicians</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#javascript">Family Members</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#python">Appointments</a>
  <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#php">Medical Records</a>
</nav>
<!--//nav-->
```

Comment: Would accordions work? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it default class (collapse) and data-toggle tag in Bootstrap 4. Please try below snippet :

```css
.doc-sub-menu {
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
          }

          .doc-sub-menu .nav-link {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 12px;
            display: block;
            color: #616670;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 34px;
            background: none;
            cursor: pointer;
          }

          .doc-sub-menu .nav-link:first-child {
            padding-top: 5px;
          }

          .doc-sub-menu .nav-link:hover {
            color: #494d55;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: none;
          }

          .doc-sub-menu .nav-link:focus {
            background: none;
          }

          .doc-sub-menu .nav-link.active {
            background: none;
            color: #40babd;
          }

          .body-blue .doc-sub-menu .nav-link.active {
            color: #58bbee;
          }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/UserGuide/Items" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#slide-submenu">Adding and Managing Items</a>
      <nav id="slide-submenu" class="doc-sub-menu nav flex-column collapse">
        <p>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#html">Medications</a>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#css">Blood Sugars</a>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#sass">Pharmacies</a>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#less">Physicians</a>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#javascript">Family Members</a>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#python">Appointments</a>
          <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#php">Medical Records</a>
        </p>
      </nav>
```

Comment: The anchor tag quit working. The anchor tag was the page and the sub menu was scrollto in the page. This is now broken  Backed out all changes and will make another try at this!